Book about a girl and her tiger in space
It's a story about a redhead girl raised mostly with tigers who ends up going into space because space pirates took her off of her planet with a tiger. She ends up being adopted by the captain of the ship. She also has a chip in her brain that helps her learn things super quickly. She eventually learns that she is the lost Princess of the biggest planet.
I read this around 2014. I remember seeing a redhead and a tiger on the cover. I don’t remember if the book was in french or in english.
